# Silverlight Animation without DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, animation, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to learn some basic animation with Silverlight. I was trying to create a Resilience Rectange

The challenge is :  I am looking to create it without DispatcherTimer. Can you help me with XAML and C# code?

Comment: 1) Look up Silverlight animations - you can define detailed storyboards which the runtime will then execture on it own.

2) Behind the scenes, the built in mechanisms are just going to use a dispatchertimer.  I'm not sure why you would be trying to avoid that.... It has to be a 'dispatcher' in order to modify something that lives on the UI thread and it has to be a 'timer' because, well, that's how animations work.  Could you explain why you are trying to avoid this?

Comment: The aim is to reduce C# coding and to do most of this in XAML. It would be great if you can share code as I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the nature of Silverlight, any interaction with the user interface is going to use a `Dispatcher` at some point and due to the nature of animation, a timer must be used to animate. Any standard Silverlight animation will use `DispatcherTimer` to achieve this. You could feasibly use your own timer and animation framework to provide animation, but there wouldn't be much point to that.

**Silverlight Animations using XAML**
Animations can be created using only XAML through the use of [`Storyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) elements and child `*Animation` elements ([`DoubleAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), [`PointAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimation%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or [`ColorAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)).

A simple example might be to fade a control in or out of view ([taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#making_a_uielement_fade_in_and_out_of_view)):

```
<UserControl x:Class="animation_ovw_intro.Page"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
  Width="400" Height="300">

  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
      <!-- Animates the rectangle's opacity. -->
      <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation
          Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedRectangle"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
          From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
          AutoReverse="True" 
          RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
       </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Margin="10">Click on the rectangle to start the animation.</TextBlock>

    <Rectangle MouseLeftButtonDown="Mouse_Clicked"
      x:Name="MyAnimatedRectangle"
      Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />

  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Using this C# to hook up the event:

```
private void Mouse_Clicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

This example animates the opacity of the `StackPanel` when the `Rectangle` is clicked, causing the `StackPanel` to fade in and out repeatedly. More complex animations can be built by animating other properties such as `Width` and `Height`, including the use of [easing functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#easing_functions) and [key frames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189038%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

**Resilience Rectangle**
To get you started on your specific problem, you can specify an animation with just a [`To`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimation.to%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) point (i.e. the corner of the rectangle) and an [easing function that will create the bouncing effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.elasticease%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). Then, on the release of the mouse button, you can start the storyboard animation and, given the appropriate values, you should get the effect you are looking for.

However, you may face some difficulties depending on which properties of your rectangle shape are read/write versus read-only as this will affect what you can animate. Possible solutions to these problems exist in either changing what properties are animated (you may need more code than XAML) or changing how the object being animated is defined.

**Other Resources**
There are many resources online for learning more about Silverlight animation. A [quick search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=silverlight%20animation&qscrl=1) garners these results:

- [Quickstart: Animations - The Official Microsoft Silverlight Site](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/animations/)
- [Video: How Do I: Animation in Silverlight 3](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/basic-animation-silverlight-3/)
- [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189090%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Silverlight Animations (Part 1 - Basic Animation)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/21/silverlight-animations-a-walkthrough.aspx)
- [Silverlight Examples & Samples](http://www.wynapse.com/Silverlight.aspx)

Comment: I think the animation he's trying to achieve (Resilience Rectangle) is better done from code since it depends on the Mouse position (where the circle is dragged). don't you think?

Comment: @AbdouMoumen: I have updated my answer. I believe this can all be done in XAML except for the trigger to the animation, which can be done in a simple event handler - however, I haven't tried it myself yet. There may be a need for more C# code, but I think that a combination of XAML and code may actually be best.